# Использование find_package в cmake

Tags: cmake

Есть своя библиотека (назовем её mylib) которую я хочу использовать в другом проекте. Есть идея сделать из нее deb пакет и установить в систему. 
И находиться она будет по следующим путям:

```
/usr/include/mylib1.0/
/usr/lib/mylib1.0/
```

и скажем другая версия

```
/usr/include/mylib1.1/
/usr/lib/mylib1.1/
```

Я хочу подключить ее в другой проект через find_package, примерно так:

```
find_package(mylib REQUIRED)
if(NOT mylib_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "Failed to find mylib")
    return()
else()
    include_directories(${mylib_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы find_package нашел мою библиотеку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы это работало нужно написать файл поиска библиотеки. Если писать по уму, то он может получиться довольно объёмным. Я приведу лишь простой пример, если хотите делать лучше — изучайте существующие файлы поиска.

Итак, создадим файл FindMyLib.cmake в папке cmake (имя может быть любым), которая находится в корне нашего проекта со следующим содержимым:

```
find_library(MY_LIB NAMES mylib PATHS /usr/lib/mylib1.0 /usr/lib/mylib1.1)
if(NOT MY_LIB)
  message(ERROR "MyLib has not been found")
else()
  message(STATUS "Found MyLib: " ${MY_LIB})
endif()
```

Теперь, в нашем основном файле cmake добавим путь, по которому он сможет узнать о существовании нашего файла поиска:

```
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
```

После чего можно использовать `find_package`.

P.S. использовать номер версии библиотеки в имени директории это не лучшая идея. Номер версии должен быть у файлов, а директория должна иметь одно имя.