# Отложенная линковка библиотек из одного sub-модуля в другой sub-модуль

Tags: cmake

Так получилось что у меня получился в какой то момент проект в котором есть sub-модуль, в котором есть sub-модуль .... 
Примерно 5-6 проектов которые каскадно друг в друге.
Это не удобно читать и использовать.
Если реализовать через find_package, то проект станет гибче, можно будет подключать sub-модуль с библиотекой или использовать какую нибудь системную.

И тогда структура будет не каскадная, а достаточно обычная. В рабочем проекте будут подключены все sub-модули.

Теперь побольше конкретики:

```
Project
   -> subs
       -> lib_one
       -> lib_two
```

Во второй библиотеке нужна логика из первой библиотеки.

1) Первая библиотека CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(One_SOURCES
    One.h
    One.cpp
)
add_library(One_LIB STATIC ${One_SOURCES})
```

2) Вторая библиотека CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(Two_SOURCES
    ./Two.cpp
    ./Two.h
)
add_library(Two_LIB STATIC ${Two_SOURCES})

find_package(One_LIB)
target_link_libraries(Two_LIB PRIVATE One_LIB)
```

В основном проекте CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

set(PROJ_NAME MAIN)
project(${PROJ_NAME})

set(SOURCES
    ./main.cpp
)
add_executable(${PROJ_NAME} ${SOURCES})

add_subdirectory(subs)

find_package(One_LIB)
target_link_libraries(${PROJ_NAME} PRIVATE One_LIB)

find_package(Two_LIB)
target_link_libraries(${PROJ_NAME} PRIVATE Two_LIB)
```

Этот примерный проект, упрощенный. И он собирается. Хотя есть Warning.
Мой же полный проект не собирается, как мне кажется по причине неправильного подключение библиотек.

Прошу помочь разобраться или возможно Вы можете поделиться ссылкой на хорошие источники на эту тему. Буду Вам очень признателен.

Comment: в приведённом примере единственная проблема — лишние команды `find_package`, для локальных целей они вообще не нужны… что не так с основным проектом сложно сказать не видя его структуру и лог сборки с ошибками… в cmake нет понятия «sub-модуль», есть «подкакталог» и «подпроект», что именно ты имеешь в виду?

Comment: Тогда в данном случае это под проекты. Идея такова, что собирая второй под проект я как бы первую библиотеку для нее подсовываю извне, в данном случае собираю ее в другом подпроекте. Но тогда наверно надо оперировать не библиотеками а пакетами?

Comment: «пакеты», в понимании `cmake`, — это отдельно установленные, заранее собранные проекты, которые являются абсолютно сторонними зависимостями по отношению к текущему проекту. Не предполагается, что их исходники будут частью текущего проекта. Для того чтобы свою библиотеку оформить как «пакет» нужно [написать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737662/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-find-package-%D0%B2-cmake) свой `Find*.cmake` файл… Если исходники зависимостей хранятся в текущем проекте, то не нужно изобретать велосипед, а просто линковать их…

Comment: Спасибо за информацию! А если просто линковать, то как сделать так что бы один из подпроектов мог воспользховаться другим подпроектом?

Comment: простой `target_link_library` должен работать... само собой, собирать надо сразу самый верхний проект...

Comment: Не могли бы Вы посмотреть мой проект если у Вас будет время: https://github.com/Rofl113/TestCore

Comment: УМВР... единственное, лишний `find_package` в `subs/Core/Core/CMakeLists.txt` и рациональность помещения библиотек в отдельные репы несколько сомнительна ИМХО...

Comment: Спасибо Вам, тестовый проект и вправду собрался. А потом собрался и основной. Если у Вас будет время, то прошу посмотрите на этот проект, может в рамках cmake что то сделано плохо или не правильно: https://github.com/Rofl113/NotebookCocos2d.git

Comment: нум, очевидно, что там сторонней библиотеки собственно нет, к которой ты пытаешься линковаться... и те же претензии с излишним дроблением на модули, что и к «тестовой»...