# Как подключить свою библиотеку к другому проекту с помощью cmake? C++

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, library

Допустим у меня есть библиотека, как мне подключить её к другому проекту с помощью cmake?
И нужно ли как-либо "собирать" эту библиотеку которую я написал для теста?

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4.0 )
project( clientlib CXX )
set( SOURCE_LIB library.cpp )
add_library( clientlib SHARED ${SOURCE_LIB} )
```

library.h

```
#ifndef SHAREDLIBRARY_LIBRARY_H
#define SHAREDLIBRARY_LIBRARY_H

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Client
{
public:
    Client(int port, std::string ip, std::string data)
    :
    port_(port),
    data_(data),
    ip_(ip)
    {
        std::cout << "Debug: Client was created (" + get_address() + ")." << std::endl;
    };

    ~Client()
    {
        std::cout << "Debug: Client was destroyed." << std::endl;
    }

    std::string get_address();
    std::string get_data();
private:
    int port_;
    std::string ip_;
    std::string data_;
};

#endif //SHAREDLIBRARY_LIBRARY_H
```

library.cpp

```
#include "library.h"


std::string Client::get_address()
{
    return std::to_string(port_) + ":" + ip_;
}

std::string Client::get_data()
{
    return data_;
}
```

Comment: как всегда, код на то он и код, что бы быть представленным в виде текста. В виде картинки он никому не нужен.

Comment: @KoVadim исправил

Comment: Для начала вам необходимо определится с видом библиотеки - заголовочная, статическая, динамическа, и сделать для этой библиотеки публичный интерфейс, который будут использовать клиенты этой библиотеки.

Comment: @user7860670, динамическая насколько я понимаю этот параметр указывается в add_library, он у меня там есть
На примере что я привел, как это все можно подключить к другому проектку средствами cmake? Что нужно прописывать в cmakelist?

Comment: Прилинкуйте ее и все - запрос в гугл cmake target link library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите прилинковать вашу библиотеку к вашей программе и они находятся в одном проекте, то это будете выглядеть примерно так:

```
 cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.4.0 )
 project( clientlib CXX )
 set( SOURCE_LIB library.cpp )
 add_library( clientlib SHARED ${SOURCE_LIB} )

 set (SOURCE_EXE main.cpp)
 add_executable( myprog ${SOURCE_EXE})
 target_link_library(myprog clientLib)
```

Если ваша библиотека находится в другом проекте, то все сложнее, нужно использовать  [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html), вот связанный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/737662/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-find-package-%D0%B2-cmake)